# The loop crashes

Tags: c++

Why does the loop crash if I enter double digit integers for searching? It works fine with the single digit integers. Help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double arr[] = { 15, 29, 38, 47, 56, 64, 72, 83 };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int n = 0; n <= size; n++) {
        cout << "Enter the number to search:  ";
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == n) {
                cout << "The number is in index no: " << i << endl
                     << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint for *one* problem: `for (int n = 0; ...) { cin >> n...` I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) as such problems should be easy to find out when debugging.

Comment: I don't see how that could *crash*.

Comment: @molbdnilo Your right, the code as shown should not crash. It might not do what the OP intended, but it should not crash.

Comment: I think your problem is
    for (int n=0;n<=size;n++)  {
    cout<<"Enter the number to search:  ";
    cin>>n;

You have loop and value entered on same variable. Check that .

Comment: A note about `endl`. `endl` is a newline and a forced flush of the stream to the underlying medium. Since writing to the media can be very expensive, you generally only want to do it when forced to, such as when you've run out of buffering space or a message must be presented immediately. All you usually want is the newline, so prefer writing a `'\n'` to the stream.

Comment: The code as a whole isn't crashing but it's the loop that is, if I input a double digit integer to search. It does gives me the index no but the program doesn't allow me to input more values to search. The loop does what it should if I input single integers though.

Answer (score 1):

Your program probably isn't crashing it is just ending earlier than you expect. As you are using `n` for both your outer loop index and your input value your loop will end after you enter a value of 8 or more as `n <= size` will return `false`.

You need to use a separate variable for your input number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double arr[] = { 15, 29, 38, 47, 56, 64, 72, 83 };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
        cout << "Enter the number to search:  ";
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == n) {
                cout << "The number is in index no: " << i << "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why is the loop working when I input only single integers? :/

Comment: @AR-Hashmi Try entering `9` as the number, it's a single digit but will have the same problem because there are ***8*** elements in your array. Again, please step through your code in a debugger, it should make it very clear when you do that and at the same time monitor all variables and their values.

Comment: Now the code works fine. I get my mistake. That was utterly silly. Thanks Alan. :)